# Data from JSON when there is a for loop inside another for loop

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON which can look like this:

```
[
   {
      "categorySlug":"essential",
      "consents":[
         {
            "consentStatus":"true",
            "label":"Essential cookie"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "categorySlug":"tracking",
      "consents":[
         {
            "consentStatus":"true",
            "label":"Tracking cookie"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "categorySlug":"marketing",
      "consents":[
         {
            "consentStatus":"true",
            "label":"Marketing cookie 1"
         },
         {
            "consentStatus":"false",
            "label":"Marketing cookie 2"
         },
         {
            "consentStatus":"true",
            "label":"Marketing cookie 3"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The `consentStatus` can be either `true` or `false`.

I need to write a function which a different status based on the `consentStatus` from every `categorySlug`.

If every `consentStatus` is true then it returns 'All consents are true'.

If the only `consentStatus` from the `categorySlug` essential is true, it returns 'Essential'.

I'm not sure how this can be done in two for loops. I tried to create a new object, but it didn't work. Or if anybody has a different idea.

Thanks!

```
categories.forEach(category => {
    category.consents.forEach(consent => {
        // Code for checks //
    })
})
```

Comment: Does the 'essential' category appear only once?

Comment: Finished my answer finally, check it please :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are seeking is already implemented as the [`some()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), at least for checking that all consents are true. In addition, to check the `essential` you can simply use a variable

You could utilize something along this way:

```js
const categories = [
    {
       "categorySlug":"essential",
       "consents":[
          {
             "consentStatus":"true",
             "label":"Essential cookie"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "categorySlug":"tracking",
       "consents":[
          {
             "consentStatus":"true",
             "label":"Tracking cookie"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "categorySlug":"marketing",
       "consents":[
          {
             "consentStatus":"true",
             "label":"Marketing cookie 1"
          },
          {
             "consentStatus":"false",
             "label":"Marketing cookie 2"
          },
          {
             "consentStatus":"true",
             "label":"Marketing cookie 3"
          }
       ]
    }
 ];
 categories.forEach(category => {
    let essential = undefined;
    if (category['categorySlug'] === 'essential') {
        essential = category['consents']['consentStatus'] === 'true';
    }
    const res = (category['consents'].some(element => {
      return element['consentStatus'] === 'false';
    }));
    if (res) {
      console.log('At least one is False');
      return;
    }
    if (essential) {
      console.log('Essentials are true');
      return;
    }
    console.log('All consents are true');
    return;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
essential = false;
all = true;

categories.forEach(category => {
if(category.categorySlug == "essential"){
    essential = category.consents.consentStatus;
}
category.consents.forEach(consent => {
  if(consents.consentStatus == false){
      all = false;
      break;
  }
})

})
return all ? "All consents are true" : (essential ? "Essential": "None")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to have 2 loops:

- The first one search the consent of the essential category while check whether the other categories are consent. If any category of the rest isn't consent we stop checking the rest.
- After the first loop where we found the essential category we could have some categories unchecked if all the previous categories was consent. So the second loop just check consents of the remaining categories.

[image]

```js
$result.textContent = getConsent();
$data.addEventListener('input', () => $result.textContent = getConsent());

function getConsent(){

  let data;
  try{
    data = eval($data.textContent);
  }catch(e){
    return e.message;
  }

  let essential, all = true;
  const isConsent = item => item.consents.every(({consentStatus}) => consentStatus === 'true');

  let idx = 0;
  while(essential === undefined && (item = data[idx++])){
    if(item.categorySlug === 'essential'){
      essential = isConsent(item);
      all && (all = essential);
      break;
    }
    // stop checking if there's already a non-consent category
    all && (all = isConsent(item));
  }
  $log.textContent = '"all" after searching for essential: ' + all;

  while(all && (item = data[idx++]) && (all = isConsent(item)));


  return all ? 'All consents are true' : essential ? 'Essential' : 'No valid consent';

}
```

```css
[id=\$result]{
 margin: 10px 0;
 padding:10px;
 background: lightgray;
 border-radius:4px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable id="$data">
[{categorySlug:"tracking",consents:[{consentStatus:"true",label:"Tracking cookie"}]},{categorySlug:"essential",consents:[{consentStatus:"true",label:"Essential cookie"}]},{categorySlug:"marketing",consents:[{consentStatus:"true",label:"Marketing cookie 1"},{consentStatus:"false",label:"Marketing cookie 2"},{consentStatus:"true",label:"Marketing cookie 3"}]}]
</div>
<div id="$result"></div>
<div id="$log"></div>
```